# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have some problems with code, help me please.

Im took all links from page with this func:

```
def get_links(link):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')
    block = soup.find('div', class_='block-top-important')
    projects = [] 
    for string in block.find_all('a', class_='post-preview-text post-preview-text--no-padding'):
        #print(string)
        projects.append ({
            string.get('href')
        })
    return(projects)
```

But when I send these links in 2nd func to crawl pages it returns me error in string 4:

```
def parse(html):
    stranica = []
    for link in html:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(link), 'lxml')
        page = soup.find(class_= 'fb-quotable')
        title = page.find('h1').text
        for main_text in page:
            main_text.text = page.find('p', class_='align-left')
        stranica.append ((title, main_text))
```

My main func, which send links in code:

```
def main():
    url = 'https://www.nur.kz/'
    op = get_html(url)
    take_links = get_links(op)
    start_parse = parse(take_links)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Full error trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\New pars.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\New pars.py", line 62, in main
    start_parse = parse(take_links)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\New pars.py", line 47, in parse
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(link), 'lxml')
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 515, in open
    req.timeout = timeout
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'timeout'
[Finished in 4.4s]
```

Comment: Can we please have a full error trace?

Comment: Sure, im added it

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I decided my problem, if someone will have same question:

Error was here:

```
        projects.append ({
            string.get('href')
        })
```

My "for" tooks links in "{}", so that's why they are "set" objects, not "string" and urllib returns error.

How I fixed it:

```
projects.append (string.get('href'))
```